# Rails 6 : use a HTML5 date field for a Ransack search filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a list of appointments, with a ransack search field to filter by date. As of now, users have to type the date, like "12/02/2022". Elsewhere in the app, I'm using a HTML5 date selector, and I've been asked to use the same type of field for the Ransack filter.

I wish I could do something like this :

```
<%= f.search_field :appointment_date_eq, as: :date %>
```

But it just don't work. I don't want to use Jquery UI, so how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.search_field :appointment_date_eq, type: :date %>
```